# Can I move from SAS HDD to SSD?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, ssd

I have an HP ML350 Gen 8 server with 8 SAS HDDs of 600 GB each. Since the drives are a little bit old now, I would like to replace them with SSDs.

I would like to know if I can do this, and if I should continue the existing RAID setup.

#### Current RAID setup:

[image: Current RAID setup]

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, you can do this. SAS is an extended form of SATA, you can use standard SATA disks on a SAS controller.

To answer your second question, you should rebuild your array on the SSDs as the block sizes will be different and thus stripe sizes will need to be adjusted to suit, otherwise you will cause excessive wear to the disks as well as hurt performance.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know should I change the RAID setup? Right now, I have RAID 1 and RAID 5.